# I do need to reorder jobs from build queue which are blocked by Block Queued Job Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I do have a job which requires external ressources and therefore it should not executed twice or more often. I used Block Queued Job Plugin to block the job if of a list of jobs is currently running.
This creates sometimes a build queue with some jobs blocked by the plugin ... which is correct.
But now I do need to reorder the build queue to give a specific build a chance to be executed.
There is usually just the fifo principle in place but I do need to overwrite this in specific situations manually.
simple queue plugin ... can not deal with blocked jobs
priority sorter .... sees to be outdated and not working for such a simple thing ...

Currently I write down the parameter handed over per job delete all and afterwards rebuild with the new order and with the parameters which were manually written down.

This is quit bad and I do need a working solution. Maybe I missed the right plugin.